# Let $\vec{u} ∈ R^n$ be such that $\vec{u}^T\vec{u} = 1$. Define the matrix $M := I − 2\vec{u}\vec{u}^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently studying for my school's qualifying exam and was having some difficulty with this linear algebra question. Given that $\vec{u} ∈ R^n$ and that $\vec{u}^T\vec{u} = 1$, with the matrix $M:= I − 2\vec{u}\vec{u}^T$, I was asked to find $M^2$, but can't work out what it would be. Any insight would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can foil the matrices out since they commute:

$$M^2 = (I - 2uu^T)^2 = I - 4uu^T + 4(uu^T)^2 = I -4uu^T + 4u(u^Tu)u^T = I$$

Where we used the fact that matrix multiplication is associative.

Comment: Thank you! I felt like I was missing a basic fact. I thought that the transpose did something funny when you were foiling.